# sql server 2012 service pack 1 or later is required upgrade

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql 2012 but I dont know which service pack.
I want to Upgrade 2014 but when ı update gives
"sql server 2012 or later is required upgrade" error.now I am downloading sql server 2012 service pack 3.but I dont know solutions.

Comment: why are you downloading sql server 2012 service pack 3?

Answer (score 0):

Running `SELECT @@VERSION` in SSMS should tell you the version of sql server you are using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
as you see service pack 1

Comment: it tells you right there that you are using Express Edition

Comment: It may be that you are required to use a full version and not the express version(which you appear to be using when looking at your results)

Comment: ı dont know just ı want to update from 2012 to 2014.gives me this error.now ı am updating sql 2012 service pack 1 to 2012 service pack 3 than again ı'll try to 2014